# Iterable container with generic datatype in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, containers

I would like to exchange numerical information in a very generic way.

- Any basic datatype such as float, int, unsigned short shall be supported...
- A container is exchanged so that one can iterate over all elements (length known at compile time)
- It shall be possible to update the value
- Basics math shall between elements of different arrays (+, -)
- The datatype should then be serialised

The closest I got is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

class BaseSignal
{
public:
  BaseSignal() {}
  BaseSignal(const BaseSignal &) = delete;
public:
  virtual const char* getBinRepr() = 0;
  virtual int getLength() = 0;
  virtual std::string getDescr() = 0;
  virtual void setValue(int) {}
  virtual void setValue(float) {}
  /* impossible because overloading based on return type is not possible */
  //virtual int getValue() {}
  //virtual float getValue() {}
};

template <typename T> class Signal: public BaseSignal
{
private:
  std::string descr;
public:
  T value;
public:
  Signal(std::string _descr, T _value)
  {
    value = _value;
    descr = _descr;
  }
  Signal(const Signal & _signal)
  {
    value = _signal.value;
    descr = _signal.descr;
  }
  const char * getBinRepr()
  {
    return (const char*) &value;
  }
  int getLength()
  {
    return sizeof(value);
  }
  std::string getDescr()
  {
    return descr;
  }
  void setValue(int _value) {value = (T)_value;}
  void setValue(float _value) {value = (T)_value;}
};


int main()
{
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>, 2> signals_old;
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>, 2> signals_new;
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>, 2> signals_delta;

  signals_old[0] = std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>(new Signal<int>("Status", 0));
  signals_old[1] = std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>(new Signal<float>("Temperature", 0.));

  signals_new[0] = std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>(new Signal<int>("Status", 1));
  signals_new[1] = std::unique_ptr<BaseSignal>(new Signal<float>("Temperature", 100.));

  /* no idea how to do basic maths */
  // signals_delta[0]->setValue(signals_old[0]->value-signals_new[0]->value);
}
```

but I am stuck with arithmetic operations, because functions cannot be overloaded based on their return types.

Any suggestions on how to implement such a generic datatype?

In Python

```
signals_old = [0, 0.]
signals_new = [1, 100.]
signals_delta[0] = signals_old[0] - signals_new[0]
```

will do the job.

I wonder if this is at all possible in C++?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic datatype"? Do you want to store multiple types in the same container?

Comment: If you want a container that can do element-wise math on numeric types, have you looked at [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)? All you'd have to add is serialization, which would be trivial for that kind of data.

Comment: there is no reason to have 2 *setValue* methods, you just need `void setValue(T _value) {value = _value;}` and the conversion is done on the argument when calling the method.Of course the *get* returns a *T*

Comment: The container should contain heterogenous type. Something like `container= [float,int,short,float]` will do in Python. Concerning 2 _setValue_: the base class must already define these functions else they cannot be accessed via the pointer to the abstract base class!

Answer (score 0):

you can use variant.
Refer to this link for details, may be it's going to help you.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: I guess that with variant I have to fall back to a specific data type as [in this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) if I do arithmetic. I would like to hide the internal datatype until I do the serialisation in the end.

Comment: In that case use Function templates with type paramers.                                         The format for declaring function templates with type parameters is:

template <class identifier> function_declaration;
template <typename identifier> function_declaration; .                                       
 Similar can be found at : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/